# state not updating when trying to paginate in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from "https://reqres.in/api" and trying to paginate it. It works fine when load first time but when I am trying to paginate it I think useState() not working fine. Please help me.

You can see all the running at at this link also. https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mendeleev-3x4gz?file=/src/dashboard.js

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import axios from "axios";
  import base_url from "../api/baseapi"
  import { func } from "prop-types";
  function Dashboard() {

    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([]);
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    // const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const getUserDetail = (userId) => {
      console.log(userId)
    }
    // function to call api
    const paginate = async (pageNum) => {
      setCurrentPage(pageNum);
    }
    const getAllUsers = (currentPage) => {
      axios.get(`${base_url}/users?page=${currentPage}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }).then(
        (response) => {
          setTotalPages(response.data.total_pages);
          setAllUsers(...allUsers, response.data.data);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      ).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(currentPage);
      getAllUsers(currentPage);
    }, [currentPage]);

    let user;
    console.log(allUsers)
    if (allUsers.length > 0) {

      user = allUsers.map(user => (
        <tr key={user.id}>
          <td>{user.id}</td>
          <td>
            <img className="img-circle" src={user.avatar} alt={user.first_name + " " + user.last_name} style={{ width: "40px" }} />
          </td>
          <td>
            {user.first_name + " " + user.last_name}
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href={`emailto:${user.email}`}>{user.email}</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ));
    }

    // equation for patination
    let renderPageNumbers = undefined;
    const pageNumbers = [];
    if (totalPages != null) {
      for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
      }
      renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
        let classes = currentPage === number ? "paginate_button active" : 'paginate_button';
        return (
          // <span key={number} onClick={() => getAllUsers(number)}>{number}</span>
          <span key={number} className={classes} onClick={() => paginate(number)}>{number}</span>
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div className="recent-items-wp notika-shadow sm-res-mg-t-30">
        <div className="rc-it-ltd">
          <div className="recent-items-ctn">
            <div className="recent-items-title">
              <h2>All Users</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="dataTables_wrapper">
            <table className="table table-striped dataTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Photo</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email Address</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {user}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="dataTables_info" id="data-table-basic_info">Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries</div>
            <div className="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="data-table-basic_paginate">
              <span onClick={() => paginate(1)} className="paginate_button previous">Previous</span>
              <span>
                {renderPageNumbers}
              </span>
              <span onClick={() => paginate(2)} className="paginate_button next">Next</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: this doesn't look right `setAllUsers(...allUsers, response.data.data);` you're missing brackets `setAllUsers([...allUsers, response.data.data])`

Comment: This question has been resolved using async await please see updated function in the below link
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mendeleev-3x4gz?file=/src/dashboard.js

Answer (score 0):

Judging the behavior of your API I've come up with this [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-leavitt-h80ii?file=/src/dashboard.js).

Using `let` in react is bad. So, I've used `state` to store the users for viewing. And changed the state on `currentPage` state change.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved using async await, I just updated below function in the above mentioned component.

```
const getAllUsers = async () => {
const headers = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};
const response = await axios.get(`${base_url}/users?page=${currentPage}`,
  { headers }
);
const data = await response;
setTotalPages(data.data.total_pages);
setAllUsers(data.data.data)};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't add sensitive const to useEffect dependences

```
useEffect( .... fetch("Items.js")....then(result) ... setPages(), [pages])
```